# Error -Element should have been select but was div

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

I get the error message when I try to select an item from a menu in a webpage. In the code below, I used the Id of the element. When I tried using the XPath instead of the Id, I got a similar error messsage.

Here is the error in full:

> An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.UnexpectedTagNameException' occurred in WebDriver.Support.dll
>
> Additional information: Element should have been select but was div

And, here is the code:

```
        //Select "Perday" for Salary Type   
        var salType = driver.FindElement(By.Id("adv-search-mobile"));
        var selectSalType = new SelectElement(salType);

        selectSalType.SelectByText("Per day");

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select class="adv-search-select sal-type-select" name="salarytype" tabindex="6"> 
    <option value="annum">Per annum</option> 
    <option value="month">Per month</option> 
    <option value="week">Per week</option> 
    <option value="day">Per day</option> 
    <option value="hour">Per hour</option> 
 </select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate good locators for elements in Web pages?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16995/how-to-generate-good-locators-for-elements-in-web-pages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is just what it says.
The element on your page with ID `adv-search-mobile` has a `<div>` tag.

You need to update your locator to get the `<select>` element (within that `<div>`. A `SelectElement` object can only be created from a `<select>`.

If you need more help, you can post your HTML.

**EDIT:**
If the `name` of your dropdown is unique, you might try:

```
var salType = driver.FindElement(By.Name("salarytype"));
```

Comment: Is this what you mean, please: 

select class="adv-search-select sal-type-select" name="salarytype" tabindex="6">
<option value="annum">Per annum</option>
<option value="month">Per month</option>
<option value="week">Per week</option>
<option value="day">Per day</option>
<option value="hour">Per hour</option>
</select>
</div>

Comment: See my edit. If that doesn't work, post the <div> tag above the <select> also.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">

        Live Actions<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

[image]