# Could not find the xpath in IE 11 browser for selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image][image]    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //div[@title='Access Client Files' and @class='cpfolder normalfolder' and @id='cpfolder_2']//span[@name='modText2']
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

My HTML is

```
<div title="Access Client Files" class="cpfolder normalfolder" id="cpfolder_2" onmouseover="hoverMod(2,true)" onmouseout="hoverMod(2,false)" onclick="javascript:showMenu('Client','ORG201','PLAN','2',false)">
  <span name="modText2">Clients</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the corresponding HTML source in your original post, please.  When using ID as a locator, you typically do not need to use other qualifiers like class and title, since the ID -should- be unique anyway, but I won't suggest an xpath until I can see some HTML code for the web element in question.

Comment: Did it work on other browsers? If you use multiple attributes together with AND operator, it will fail if it doesn't find one of them, even if others are found. Also, check this resource https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16995/how-to-generate-good-locators-for-elements-in-web-pages

Comment: Right click on the web element that you want to find, and click Inspect Element. It will then display the code section for the the element.

Comment: Selenium can have issues with compound classes such as `class="cpfolder normalfolder"`. You would be better to use only ID as a selector.

Comment: i tried driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cpfolder_2']")).click();    didnt work,  same error - unable to find the xpath

Comment: It may be inside an iframe.  Again, this is something we can't tell without seeing more of the HTML

Comment: Hi Bill you are correct, It has frame and i tried all the ways ..even CSS , but i am still getting the error ..please see the code attached in .jpeg file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to search what is marked in your screen-shots but not what you describe in HTML snippet (because they are different elements) and assuming the frame with `id="did_appframe"` is the top-level frame I would recommend to try the following code:

```
driver.
        switchTo()
            .frame("did_appframe")
        .switchTo()
            .frame("did_cp_display")
        .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Access Assignee Files']"));
```

This basically means that you need to "drill" to the frames one-by-one starting from the very top unless you're in the one where your target element resides.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, it worked. after the page loads selenium took almost 35 secs to identify the element, is  there any way which i can increase the speed to identify and click on the element

Comment: You can try different selector types. For example CSS selector. Some say CSS selectors work faster.

Answer (score 2):

If resetting your IE settings back to default doesn't work, I was able to solve the problem by lowering the the security level in "Internet Options" in the Internet zone from "High" to "Medium-high" or "Medium" (IE11, win10).  I changed the capabilities by setting some properties for IE and it worked. Here's the code snippet:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, Configuration.getConfig("My URL"));
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for ur help, but it has frame, and i could not identify the element. i have attached the frame code above..

Answer (score 0):

You may use CSS selector.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[name=\"modText2\"]"));
 System.out.println(element.getText()); //Should print out "Clients"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur help, but it has frame, and i could not identify the element. i have attached the frame code above..